# Entire battery drains even though `[s2idle] deep` is available in my "/sys/power/mem_sleep" file

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management, asus, battery

After I suspend my laptop for ~10 hours, the laptop dies with the entire battery drained. I use "cat /sys/power/mem_sleep" to check the suspend mode and it returns "[s2idle] deep". Doesn't it mean I have the advance suspend mode that drains very little power during suspension?

I tried "sudo journalctl | grep "PM: suspend" | tail -2" after I suspended and woke up the laptop. It returns

```
Feb 16 10:46:42 Zephyrus kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Feb 16 10:46:53 Zephyrus kernel: PM: suspend exit
```

which means that it didn't go into the suspend to ram mode, instead it goes into the power-draining s2idle mode. How can I fix this? Thank you!

It's a ROG M16 with ubuntu 20.04.

EDIT: I followed this [article](https://learnubuntumate.weebly.com/draining-battery.html) and I can have "suspend entry (deep)
" now. Whether the battery is still drained remains to be checked.

Answer (score 4):

I basically followed this [article](https://learnubuntumate.weebly.com/draining-battery.html) and some other instructions.

First, just whether your device is in the "suspend to RAM" using

```
cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
```

If it returns "s2idle [deep]", then it's supported. If it's not. First check whether your device supports this suspend mode, if so, run

```
echo 'deep' > /sys/power/mem_sleep
```

and check again.

Now your device has the correct suspend mode, but it doesn't necessarily enter this mode when you suspend. To check, first suspend your device, then wake it up. Then open a terminal and run

```
sudo journalctl | grep "PM: suspend" | tail -2
```

You can find the log of your suspension, which is something similar to below.  Note that the log I attached shows that I correctly enter the "suspend to RAM" mode, in your case, it may appear "suspend entry (s2idle)" instead of "suspend entry (deep)"

```
lin@Zephyrus:~$ sudo journalctl | grep "PM: suspend" | tail -2
[sudo] password for lin: 
Feb 16 21:35:05 Zephyrus kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Feb 17 09:36:24 Zephyrus kernel: PM: suspend exit
```

If this is the case, you have to modify your bootloader. Here I use the gedit. Make sure it's installed first by

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install gedit
```

Then modify the bootloader file

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Locate the line **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"** in the file and replace it with **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"**

It should work now! Try to suspend and wake up your device and check the log using the command above again!

Comment: What is `mem_sleep_default=deep` doing? Is it a BIOS issue? Why can't it be set after boot? Is this related to Microsoft wanting network access during `sleep`?

Comment: I am not an expert on it. My understanding is that it commands the device to enter the "s2idle [deep]" when suspended instead of "s2idle".

Comment: If I **configure disk in bios from raid to ahci**, the machine uses much less power during sleep. I am using 7770. No matter what parameter I pass to kernel, I always get: [s2idle]
from cat /sys/power/mem_sleep

Comment: Last (missing) step:
sudo update-grub