# Ubuntu 22.04 - suspend then hibernate failed with result 'dependency'

Tags: suspend, battery, hibernate, modprobe

Recently the suspend-to-hibernate function stopped working reliably. It happens that my battery is drained, although it should have went into hibernation.

This is what

```
journalctl | grep suspend
```

shows:

```
Nov 26 05:09:15 XYZ kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Nov 26 05:09:15 XYZ kernel: PM: suspend exit
Nov 26 05:09:15 XYZ systemd[1]: systemd-suspend-then-hibernate.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 26 05:09:15 XYZ systemd[1]: systemd-suspend-then-hibernate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 26 05:09:15 XYZ systemd[1]: suspend-then-hibernate.target: Job suspend-then-hibernate.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Nov 26 05:09:15 XYZ systemd[1]: systemd-suspend-then-hibernate.service: Consumed 2.151s CPU time.
Nov 26 05:09:15 XYZ ModemManager[1057]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Nov 26 05:09:15 XYZ systemd-sleep[137140]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Nov 26 05:09:15 XYZ kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Nov 26 05:09:35 XYZ kernel: PM: suspend exit
Nov 26 05:09:35 XYZ kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
```

And this just happened in a cycle, until the battery was drained. So my understanding is, somehow there is a dependency, that prevents it from hibernation?

Performing suspend or hibernate via terminal works fine:

```
systemctl suspend
Nov 26 16:39:11 XYZ ModemManager[933]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Nov 26 16:39:14 XYZ systemd-sleep[19184]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Nov 26 16:39:14 XYZ kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Nov 26 16:39:27 XYZ kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Nov 26 16:39:27 XYZ kernel: PM: suspend exit
Nov 26 16:39:27 XYZ systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 26 17:21:10 XYZ ModemManager[933]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Nov 26 17:22:31 XYZ kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
```

Any ideas?

**Update:**

Seems I cut off the journalctl content at the wrong place. I did now the following:

1. perform sudo systemctl suspend, then save journalctl
2. perform sudo hibernate, then save journalctl
3. perform sudo suspend-then-hibernate, then save journalctl
4. close the lid (which should trigger suspend-then-hibernate), then save journalctl

This showed that #1-3 are working fine, while #4 fails. Here the relevant log part for #3:

```
Dez 12 20:52:05 XYZ systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Dez 12 20:52:05 XYZ systemd[1]: Starting Suspend; Hibernate if not used for a period of time...
Dez 12 20:52:05 XYZ systemd-sleep[8780]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Dez 12 20:52:05 XYZ kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Dez 12 20:52:26 XYZ kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.006 seconds
Dez 12 20:52:26 XYZ kernel: Freezing user space processes
Dez 12 20:52:26 XYZ kernel: Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.004 seconds)
Dez 12 20:52:26 XYZ kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Dez 12 20:52:26 XYZ kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks
Dez 12 20:52:26 XYZ kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
```

and for #4:

```
Dez 12 21:19:10 XYZ systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Dez 12 21:19:10 XYZ systemd[1]: Starting Suspend; Hibernate if not used for a period of time...
Dez 12 21:19:10 XYZ systemd-sleep[19771]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Dez 12 21:19:10 XYZ kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Dez 12 21:19:10 XYZ kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.033 seconds
Dez 12 21:19:30 XYZ kernel: Freezing user space processes
Dez 12 21:19:30 XYZ kernel: Freezing user space processes failed after 20.007 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
Dez 12 21:19:30 XYZ kernel: task:modprobe        state:D stack:0     pid:19662 ppid:1948   flags:0x00004006
Dez 12 21:19:30 XYZ kernel: Call Trace:
```

And this behaviour just repeats itself, until the battery is drained. Searching for modprobe did not give any clarity to this.
Any ideas?

**Update 2:**

Think I've found the issue.. I often have to restart pulseaudio (via pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload, from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230888/is-there-another-way-to-restart-the-sound-system-if-pulseaudio-alsa-dont-work)), due to audio issues and seems this procedure is running in the background and blocking it then *facepalm*. A fast check of lid-closing with successful trigger of suspend-then-hibernate after a fresh restart confirmed this for now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't post logvomit ("here's my guess at all the data - you figure it out").

Diagnostic procedure:

First step is to put a pin in the timestream with

```
date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp
```

Then, do your suspend/shutdown thing. When your system is usable again,

```
sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"
```

This will show you all the log messages since you set `pin.tmp`. Some messages relate to your problem.

Alternatively,

After the system comes up again, the terminal command `sudo journalctl   b -1 -ex` will show the system logs leading up to the crash/shutdown. You can look at other shutdowns by varying the `-b -1` option. If nothing stands out, suspect overheating or sudden power outage. Do `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`, read `man journalctl`. For more `journalctl` help, see my AskUbuntu profile (click on my username).

Comment: Thanks for the kind hint...

I saw the recommendation in this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455199/entire-battery-drains-even-though-s2idle-deep-is-available-in-my-sys-power, which sounds similar, but did not solve it.

The "logvomit" is what my system tried last time (thus, morning 5 AM) before the battery drained.